how to clang-format long array of strings, to have strings in multiple columns
Below is the clang-format of ".h" header file with variable size of strings.
string a[x] = {
    "masfasdno",
    "iasdst",
    "xafdsfayz",
    "pqssssr",
    "mnaado",
    "ist",
    "asdlfkjlkjsad",
    "iasdst",
    "xafasdfsdfsadsfayz",
    "pqssssr",
    "mnaado",
    "ist",
    "asdlfkjlkjsad",
    "kjsakjfksn",
    "lasldfnj",
    "xymnz",
    "pqafr",
    "masfasdno",
    "iasdsadfasdfasdfat",
    "xafdsfayz",
    "pqssssr",
    "mnaado",
    "ist",
    "asdlfkjlkjsad",
    "kjsakjfksn",
    "lasldfnj",
    "xymnz",
    "pqafr",
    "masfasdno",
    "iasdst",
    "xafdsfayz",
    "pqsssadfadasfadfsr",
    "mnaado",
    "ist",
}

The above causing file to be too long to work with. I would like to have strings formatted into multiple row:
string a[x] = {
    "xymnz",     "masfasdno",   "asjnkjkjb",
    "pqafr",     "masfasdno",   "jnjkbk",
    "masfasdno", "afassaf",     "aksdjfnlkc",
    "iasdst",    "kjbckjasas",  "sajnk",
    "xafdsfayz", "jknkljxakjas","askfnsjdns", 
    "pqssssr",   "skjfkajk",    "akjf",
}

Here is the the version:

Ubuntu clang-format version 16.0.6 (15)

below is my clang-format config:
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignArrayOfStructures: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled:         false
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments:  false
  AlignCompound:   false
  PadOperators:    false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind:            Always
  OverEmptyLines:  0
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakArrays:   true 
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeInlineASMColon: OnlyMultiline
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IfMacros:
  - KJ_IF_MAYBE
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentRequiresClause: true
IndentWidth:     2
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertBraces:    false
InsertNewlineAtEOF: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
IntegerLiteralSeparator:
  Binary:          0
  BinaryMinDigits: 0
  Decimal:         0
  DecimalMinDigits: 0
  Hex:             0
  HexMinDigits:    0
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
LineEnding:      DeriveLF
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PackConstructorInitializers: BinPack
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Right
PPIndentWidth:   -1
QualifierAlignment: Leave
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
ReflowComments:  true
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Leave
ShortNamespaceLines: 1
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SortJavaStaticImport: Before
SortUsingDeclarations: LexicographicNumeric
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterIfMacros:   true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  Never
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum:         1
  Maximum:         -1
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Latest
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - STRINGIZE
...


setting "BreakArrays: false" had no effect.

@3CxEZiVlQ when comma removed, whole column moves towards right

@3CxEZiVlQ I have updated the data above, can you try with that.

One way I could manage to preserve columns is by turning of the clang-format before and after the section I wanted to to be unchanged. A simple work around would be:
string a[x] = {
    // clang-format off
    "xymnz",     "masfasdno",   "asjnkjkjb",
    "pqafr",     "masfasdno",   "jnjkbk",
    "masfasdno", "afassaf",     "aksdjfnlkc",
    "iasdst",    "kjbckjasas",  "sajnk",
    "xafdsfayz", "jknkljxakjas","askfnsjdns", 
    "pqssssr",   "skjfkajk",    "akjf",
    // clang-format on
}


